# Pasting Range from Excel to Ppt as image

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Hi have a code that Copy Range from Excel to Ppt as image.
However when I give command for it to resize Height width top left it is not doing it bcoz of default setting of Lock Aspect ratio. Is there any way I can modify my code.

Comment: No images of code please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69364951/edit) the question and format as a code block.

Comment: Is the macro in Excel or Powerpoint ?

Comment: It is a excel macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `.LockAspectRatio` property of the shape to  `msoFalse`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ppt()

    Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    
    Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPTApp.Visible = True
    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add
    Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

    Range("A1:C10").Copy
    With PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteMetafilePicture)
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Left = 20
        .Top = 20
        .Width = 400
        .Height = 300
    End With
    
End Sub
```